# Specify route to an interface in Windows cmd

Tags: route, windows-command-prompt, interface, static-routes

I have a computer with 2 network interfaces. 
One interface is connected to LAN network with IP 192.168.0.254, and the other is connected to a recorder server (192.168.0.233).
192.168.0.10 is the gateway for the LAN.
When I try to ping to 192.168.0.6, Windows first tries a route to the interface without network (192.168.0.233);
I want to add a route to 192.168.0.6/255.255.255.0 specifing I want to use the interface 192.168.0.254 when I try to ping 192.168.0.6.
I have tried:

```
route add 192.168.0.6 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.10 if 13
```

Here is a print of my interfaces:

[image: screenshot 1]

When I add the static route to the table, it doesn't show the specified interface, only associate it to the gateway.

[image: screenshot 2]

Is it correct?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To specify the interface in windows route command, you are supposed to use 'IF'... Uppercase letters, not lowercase.

Also, where you are specifying you want to add a route to a single IP 192.168.0.6, you need to use a subnet mask of 255.255.255.255.

The subnet mask of 255.255.255.255 specifies a single host. A subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 specifies 192.168.0.X where X=1-254

So, your command should be:

```
route add 192.168.0.6 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.10 IF 13
```

Looking again at your question, the best solution for you may be to use your LAN side like a normal 192.168.0.X network... But for the recorder server, I would recommend specifying a different network: Recorder server IP of 192.168.10.233, and then your second network interface should be 192.168.10.2. This will eliminate the need to manually configure routes, and may simplify everything for you.

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
route add 192.168.0.6 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
```

If you want persistence:

```
route -p add 192.168.0.6 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
```

Not sure what the "if" was for, but try this for cost:

```
route add 192.168.0.6 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254 metric 13
```

Comment: "if" was for interface, so "IF".